# Save a list of object return Cannot deserialize error

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I use spring boot and thymeleaf
I try to save a list of object.

My object.

```
public class GECPD {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public List<GEPD> geL;
    public Integer giId;     
    public Integer sGEId;
}
```

In my controller i return a list of object

```
  Set<GECPD> gECL = new HashSet<>();
  ...
  model.addAttribute("gECL", new ArrayList<>(gECL));
```

Data is diplayed correctly

```
<input name="id[0]" type="hidden" value="136">
<select name="sGEId[0]" class="form-control">
 <option value="246">01</option>
    <option value="391">00</option>
</select>
```

My controller

```
  @PutMapping(value = "/{id}/ge")
  public ResponseEntity updateGE(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody List<GECPD> dto) {
        ....
        return new ResponseEntity(dto,HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

function saveGroundElement(){

```
var form = transForm.serialize('#gEForm');
var url = "/rest/spi/"  + $("#spi").val() + "/ge";
form = JSON.stringify(form);
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "put",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: form,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {

        checkError(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

}

Data sent

```
{"id":["136"],"sGEId":["246"]}
```

I get this result

> Erreur: { "timestamp" : "2018-06-29T15:36:58.427+0000", "status" :
>   400, "error" : "Bad Request", "message" : "JSON parse error: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
>   "path" : "/rest/spi/1/ge" }

Any idea?

Comment: You need to send array, not an object

Comment: ok but how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your frontend side is ok... you need to modify your server side

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}/ge")
  public ResponseEntity updateGE(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody GECPDList dto) {
        ....
        return new ResponseEntity(dto,HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

In GECPDS

```
public GECPDList class{
    private List<GECPD> gecpds;
}
```